# How to display pyBarcode generated image on web without saving

Tags: python, image, pyramid

I want to display the png or svg barcode generated by [pyBarcode](http://pythonhosted.org/pyBarcode/) on a webpage. But I'm thinking it would be better if I don't have to save the image on the server. Is there anyway I can do this with [pyBarcode](http://pythonhosted.org/pyBarcode/)? or with any other barcode image generation method with python?

I'm using [pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) as the web framework, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the barcode straight out to the [`response.body_file`](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.Response.body_file):

```
barcode.writer import ImageWriter
ean = barcode.get_barcode('ean', '123456789102', writer=ImageWriter())

response = request.response
response.content_type = 'image/png'
ean.write(response.body_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how you can serve a file thats not even created . Consider saving it in /tmp if it won't be required for a long time but you will create and serve it once.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by creating a HTTP response that returns the file object.

So that the request to "http://mysite.com/someimage.png" returns the file contents.

Try writing to the [`pyramid.response.Response`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.Response) object's `.body_file`.